# Checking if the player was grounded in the previous frame?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a CharacterController and I am trying to check if the player was grounded in the last frame but not in the current frame so that I can perform a certain action.

I've done something similar before where I checked the player's `transform.position` in two different frames which was pretty straight forward but I'm not sure how to approach it when it comes to a bool like `isGrounded`.

All I use when it comes to the ground check is `bool isGrounded = controller.isGrounded;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your update step, store a variable

```
bool m_wasGroundedLastFrame = true;

void Update() 
{
   ... 
   m_wasGroundedLastFrame = controller.isGrounded;
}
```

then just check this variable as normal in your code:

```
var test = m_wasGroundedLastFrame && !controller.isGrounded;
```

If you're using `Update` and not `FixedUpdate` you could make this super explicit by using `LateUpdate`

```
void LateUpdate() 
{
   m_wasGroundedLastFrame = controller.isGrounded;
}
```

but the first method will work fine too.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. There's just one issue with trying to get my character controller to snap to the ground once the var test turns true, but I suppose that's an issue for another question. I appreciate the detail.

Answer (score 0):

just store the current value and use it next frame:

```
bool lastIsGrounded;

void Update(){
    //use lastIsGrounded
  
    lastIsGrounded = characterController.isGrounded;
}
```